# Jackson2 many to many deserialization

Tags: json, jackson

I have two classes Events and Users which have a many to many relationship.

```
public class Event {

    private int id;

  private List<Users> users;
}

public class User {
        private int id;

      private List<Event> events;
}
```

I have read @JsonIdentityInfo annotation is supposed to help but I cannot see an example of this.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use `@JsonIdentityInfo` in the two classes `User` and `Event` this way:

```java
import java.util.List;

import com.fasterxml.jackson.annotation.JsonIdentityInfo;
import com.fasterxml.jackson.annotation.ObjectIdGenerators;

@JsonIdentityInfo(generator = ObjectIdGenerators.UUIDGenerator.class, property="@UUID")
public class User
{
    private int id;
    private List<Event> events;

    // Getters and setters
}
```

... and

```java
import java.util.List;

import com.fasterxml.jackson.annotation.JsonIdentityInfo;
import com.fasterxml.jackson.annotation.ObjectIdGenerators;

@JsonIdentityInfo(generator = ObjectIdGenerators.UUIDGenerator.class, property="@UUID")
public class Event
{
    private int id;
    private List<User> users;

    // Getters and setters
}
```

You can use any of the `ObjectIdGenerator`s as appropriate. Now, serialization and deserialization of the objects that correspond to the many to many mapping will succeed:

```java
public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException
{
    ObjectMapper objectMapper = new ObjectMapper();
    objectMapper.configure(SerializationFeature.INDENT_OUTPUT, true);

    Event event1 = new Event();
    event1.setId(1);
    Event event2 = new Event();
    event2.setId(2);

    User user = new User();
    user.setId(10);

    event1.setUsers(Arrays.asList(user));
    event2.setUsers(Arrays.asList(user));
    user.setEvents(Arrays.asList(event1, event2));

    String json = objectMapper.writeValueAsString(user);
    System.out.println(json);

    User deserializedUser = objectMapper.readValue(json, User.class);
    System.out.println(deserializedUser);
}
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: Thanks. The issue I am having is that I receive the string from REST API call. User object looks something like{"_id": "51f1f8acf3ce41b062000005","events": [{"_id":"51f1fccef3ce41b062000007","users": [{"_id": "51f1f8acf3ce41b062000005"}],}]}.So a the request returns current user, the list of events and users at the event. I have used ObjectIdGenerators.PropertyGenerator.class, property="_id" which works. But since User object _id is repeated in the event array I get an exception Already had POJO for id through reference chain: models.User["events"]->models.Event["users"]->models.User["_id"]

Comment: Hmm. The code samples in my answer should ideally work fine. But if you're facing issues with the ID property, you can try using different `property` values in the `@JsonIdentityInfo` annotation in `User.java` and `Event.java` (say `property="userId"` and `property="eventId"` respectively).

Comment: https://www.toptal.com/javascript/bidirectional-relationship-in-json this article explain the @JsonIdentityInfo annotation you can get more understanding referring it.

Answer (score 1):

I came here "googling", so I ended up using @Jackall's anwers, with a little mod

```
@JsonIdentityInfo(generator = ObjectIdGenerators.PropertyGenerator.class, property = "id")
```

This is 'cause my DTO's have a property called "id", like Event and User classes from the question.

Answer (score 0):

Try to use the "scope" property, inside your JsonIdentityInfo annotation:

```
@JsonIdentityInfo(
    generator = ObjectIdGenerators.UUIDGenerator.class,   
    property="@UUID",
    scope=YourPojo.class
)
```

Comment: Scope has no effect on the UUIDGenerator. From the docs... One difference to other generators is that scope is always set as <code>Object.class</code> (regardless of arguments): this because UUIDs are globally unique, and scope has no meaning.