# Post Request for spring boot server

Tags: java, spring-boot

i have a problem with post request. My server has 3 entities Product, Order and User. I want to create new Orders with Products that are already created in my database and with already created Users. I just need to connect them in another table

```
@Entity
@Table (name = "orders")

@Data
@AllArgsConstructor
@NoArgsConstructor
public class Order {
@Id
@Column( name = "id")
@GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
private UUID id;

    @Column(name = "notion")
    private String notion;
    
    
    @ManyToOne
    @JoinColumn(name = "user_id")
    private User user;
    
    @ManyToMany(cascade = {CascadeType.MERGE, CascadeType.PERSIST})
    @JoinTable(
            name = "order_product",
            joinColumns = @JoinColumn(name = "order_id", referencedColumnName = "id"),
            inverseJoinColumns = @JoinColumn(name = "product_id", referencedColumnName = "id")
    )
    @JsonManagedReference
    private List<Product> products;

}
```

```
@Entity
@Table (name = "products")
@Data
@NoArgsConstructor
@AllArgsConstructor
public class Product {
@Id
@Column (name = "id")
@GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
private UUID id;

    @Column (name = "name")
    private String name;
    
    @Column(name = "description")
    private String description;
    
    
    @Column (name = "price")
    private Integer price;
    
    @ManyToMany(mappedBy = "products")
    @JsonBackReference
    private List<Order> orders;

}
```

```
@Entity
@Table (name = "users")

@Data
@AllArgsConstructor
@NoArgsConstructor
public class User {
@Id
@Column (name = "id")
@GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
private UUID id;

    @Column(name = "username")
    private String username;
    
    @Column (name = "email", unique = true)
    private String email;
    
    @Column (name = "phoneNumber")
    private String phoneNumber;

}
```

this is method in controller to create new Order

```
@PostMapping("/add")
public ResponseEntity\<?\> addNewOrder(@Validated @RequestBody OrderWithProductsRequest request){
try {
Order order = request.getOrder();
List \<UUID\> productsId = request.getProductIds();

            orderService.addNewOrder(order, productsId);
            return ResponseEntity.ok ("New order is added");
        } catch (Exception e ){
            e.printStackTrace();
            return ResponseEntity.status(HttpStatus.INTERNAL_SERVER_ERROR)
                    .body("Error creating user");
        }
    }
```

this is support class for creating new Order

```
@Data
@AllArgsConstructor
@NoArgsConstructor
public class OrderWithProductsRequest {
private Order order;
private List\<UUID\> productIds;
}
```

this is my Order Server method that adds new order

```
@Transactional
public void addNewOrder(Order order, List\<UUID\> productIds) {
try {
List\<Product\> products = productRepository.findAllById(productIds);
order.setProducts(products);
orderRepository.save(order);
log.info("Saved order with id: {}", order.getId());
} catch (Exception e) {
log.error("Error adding new order: {}", e.getMessage());
throw new RuntimeException("Error adding new order", e);
}
}
```

this is the request i try and i use Postman with property Json file

```
    {
      "order": {
        "notion": "Your Notion Value Here",
        "user": {
          "id": "2d3d16e5-3464-4f8d-a590-b4c0c60ad8e9"
        }
      },
      "productIds": [
        "9b9a0688-608a-4548-9ca4-4989e92c0a24"
      ]
    }
```

this is the mistakes from terminal intellij

```
2023-09-30T01:41:02.367+02:00  WARN 89880 --- [nio-8080-exec-2] .c.j.MappingJackson2HttpMessageConverter : Failed to evaluate Jackson deserialization for type [[simple type, class com.example.serverjava.Entity.OrderWithProductsRequest]]: com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.exc.InvalidDefinitionException: Cannot handle managed/back reference 'defaultReference': back reference type (`java.util.List<com.example.serverjava.Entity.Order>`) not compatible with managed type (com.example.serverjava.Entity.Order)
2023-09-30T01:41:02.370+02:00  WARN 89880 --- [nio-8080-exec-2] .w.s.m.s.DefaultHandlerExceptionResolver : Resolved [org.springframework.web.HttpMediaTypeNotSupportedException: Content-Type 'application/json;charset=UTF-8' is not supported]
```

this is the mistake i get in response

```
{
    "timestamp": 1696030862377,
    "status": 415,
    "error": "Unsupported Media Type",
    "trace": "org.springframework.web.HttpMediaTypeNotSupportedException: Content-Type 'application/json;charset=UTF-8' is not supported\n\tat org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.AbstractMessageConverterMethodArgumentResolver.readWithMessageConverters(AbstractMessageConverterMethodArgumentResolver.java:209)\n\tat org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestResponseBodyMethodProcessor.readWithMessageConverters(RequestResponseBodyMethodProcessor.java:163)\n\tat org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestResponseBodyMethodProcessor.resolveArgument(RequestResponseBodyMethodProcessor.java:136)\n\tat org.springframework.web.method.support.HandlerMethodArgumentResolverComposite.resolveArgument(HandlerMethodArgumentResolverComposite.java:122)\n\tat org.springframework.web.method.support.InvocableHandlerMethod.getMethodArgumentValues(InvocableHandlerMethod.java:179)\n\tat org.springframework.web.method.support.InvocableHandlerMethod.invokeForRequest(InvocableHandlerMethod.java:146)\n\tat org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.ServletInvocableHandlerMethod.invokeAndHandle(ServletInvocableHandlerMethod.java:118)\n\tat org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.invokeHandlerMethod(RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.java:884)\n\tat org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.handleInternal(RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.java:797)\n\tat org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.AbstractHandlerMethodAdapter.handle(AbstractHandlerMethodAdapter.java:87)\n\tat org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doDispatch(DispatcherServlet.java:1081)\n\tat org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doService(DispatcherServlet.java:974)\n\tat org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.processRequest(FrameworkServlet.java:1011)\n\tat org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.doPost(FrameworkServlet.java:914)\n\tat jakarta.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:590)\n\tat org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.service(FrameworkServlet.java:885)\n\tat jakarta.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:658)\n\tat org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:205)\n\tat org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:149)\n\tat org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:51)\n\tat org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:174)\n\tat org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:149)\n\tat org.springframework.web.filter.CharacterEncodingFilter.doFilterInternal(CharacterEncodingFilter.java:201)\n\tat org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:116)\n\tat org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:174)\n\tat org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:149)\n\tat org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:167)\n\tat org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:90)\n\tat org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:482)\n\tat org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:115)\n\tat org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:93)\n\tat org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:74)\n\tat org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:341)\n\tat org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Processor.service(Http11Processor.java:391)\n\tat org.apache.coyote.AbstractProcessorLight.process(AbstractProcessorLight.java:63)\n\tat org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$ConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:894)\n\tat org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.doRun(NioEndpoint.java:1740)\n\tat org.apache.tomcat.util.net.SocketProcessorBase.run(SocketProcessorBase.java:52)\n\tat org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1191)\n\tat org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:659)\n\tat org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.TaskThread$WrappingRunnable.run(TaskThread.java:61)\n\tat java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:833)\n",
    "message": "Content-Type 'application/json;charset=UTF-8' is not supported.",
    "path": "/api/order/add"
}
```

need help please......

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55710647/deserialize-jsonmanagedreference-on-many-to-many-relations

Comment: Not 100% related, but you have a few ticking bombs in that code. A strong suggestion: drop lombok and spring-jpa. The use of `@Data` on hibernate classes can bring a lot of pain when they are used in any kind of collection (e.g.  `private List<Product> products;`). It's also a bad practice (and a nightmare) to use the JPA entities to serialise from/into json as those 2 will probably be different in structure.